# Is there any documentation on how screen readers should act?

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

I'm reviewing and recommending changes/fixes to a small web application which was recently enhanced to be more accessible.

The problem I keep running into is that there doesn't seem to be anything which details how screen readers should (or even do) work.

For instance, if you look at the  [Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA) 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-wai-aria-20110118/roles#tabpanel) specification for a TabPanel and the Authoring Practices guide state a basic definition and how it works, but doesn't really answer a question like "should the screenreader speak the contents of the TabPanel when it becomes visible?"

That example is problematic in that I need to convince the business requirements it shouldn't be spoken, yet nothing actually says one way or the other. (The best I can do is point out that the examples from the Authoring Practices guide are not spoken.)

For that, and a half dozen other issues it would be really nice to have a guide that says "This is what a screen reader does (or should do) when it encounters this element/role."

Does that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some very simple principles:

1. Screen readers will default to start reading the page in DOM order from the beginning to the end. This will be preceded by some basic stats of the page such as the title and the number of links, headings etc. However users will generally not simply allow the screen reader to completely read an entire page and will interrupt the reading to start navigating
2. If a user knows the page, they will choose a way to navigate to the things they know on the page. Common navigation mechanisms are by headings, forms, landmarks, links, tables etc. If the user does not know the page, they may navigate and explore using different strategies similar to the way that a sighted user would scan a page with her eyes.
3. When the user navigates, they move their virtual cursor. Normally the focus will follow this cursor jumping from focusable element to focusable element as they are encountered (this is configurable). The screen reader will read out whatever it encounters as the user navigates this. This is akin to a sighted user scanning the page for what to read. The key here is that THE USER NEEDS TO CONTROL WHAT IS READ OUT by navigating around. The one caveat for this is that if the user activates a control that causes some other part of the page to be updated and a sighted user would expect to know that it has updated immediately or know its value, then the application should read this out using ARIA-LIVE.

As you will note, that last point is where this crosses from the technical accessibility into the usability realm. Here are some common mis-conceptions that novices hold.

1. You need to make everything tab focusable for screen readers: NO you do not, the screen reader can see everything without it being tab focusable,
2. You need to announce every update to the page: NO you do not. If a user is interacting with a tab, they know through experience, that selecting the tab will expose its contents and there are keyboard commands to get to that content. You do not need to even tell them that the tab has been shown, you simply need to update the selected state of the tab.
3. You don't need to announce anything: NO, you do need to decide which information is important enough to announce automatically. For example, if you are implementing a chat application, it would be dumb if the user had to navigate around to hear that messages have arrived from her friends. These should be announced automatically.

I strongly suggest that you bring a blind screen reader user into your organization and have them demonstrate to your execs how they do things to illustrate these points.

Comment: "You need to make everthing tab focusable for screen readers : NO". Of course not for screen readers, but without forgetting that everything should be operable through keyboard.

Comment: yes, but what I am talking about is people thinking they need to make headings and paragraph tags tab focusable

Comment: It's my first month and I'm a contractor... don't think I'm going to be bringing anyone into the organization all that soon! ;) Thanks, for the info though!

Answer (score 2):

1. **UAAG**

You have to look at the User Agent Accessibility Guidelines (UAAG):
http://www.w3.org/TR/UAAG20-Reference/

They are not intended to define what a screenreader might do but what informations must give the user agent to assistive technologies.

For instance, for giving the focus to a tab panel, you can read the following points:

- 2.1.4 Separate Selection from Activation
- 3.3.1 Avoid Unpredictable Focus
- Guideline 4.1 - Facilitate programmatic access to assistive technology
- 5.1.1 Comply with WCAG

  2. **WCAG**

The WCAG defines what a web developper should do to make his content accessible. It wont tell you how the screen-reader will react, but how you should act to provide the needed informations.

For instance, the focus does not have to trigger a change of context 
http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20150226/G107
But as long as the user ask a change of context, that's ok.

And the position of the focus will then define the data to be read, except the case of aria live regions.

3. **Important** : Accessibility and screen-readers are two different things

You can't resume your accessibility policy to screenreaders only.

And you won't find guidelines oriented to screenreaders only. They are made the general way to not forget all kind of people with disabilities.

**That being said,** a screenreader will chose the way it acts in the most predictable way. The only thing you might do is testing that your application complies with a logical way of doing things. And if a screenreader does not act as normal, it might be a misconception that could be improved either in your code, either in the assistive technology.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound like an opinion answer, but I believe there's no reliable documentation - mainly because each individual accessibility user has particular requirements of their screenreader. Some don't need text to be spoken aloud while others do. Some have selective preference of what is spoken out. You're even able to change the speed at which text is spoken aloud.

Since all of the major screenreaders are *highly* customizable down to extremely minute details, this is all dealer's choice.

However, by having the standards and requirements set out for developers to follow and produce consistent applications, it allows the screenreader to interpret information consistently so that the user has the best experience possible. How the screenreader relays this experience is purely up to the user.

One small note, I've addressed my answer directly to screen readers and **not** the typical WCAG/ARIA guidelines which are widely available and specific enough to achieve what you need as a developer.